# Url.Action returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to build a email confrimation link using asp.net core 3. After generating the token, generating a confirmEmail link with this code always returns null.

```
var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            var confirmationLink = Url.Action(
                "ConfirmEmail",
                "Users",
                new { userId = user.Id, token }, protocol: Request.Scheme
                );
```

This is a .net core 3 web api project no mvc. In start up the configuration is to use: app.UseRouting().

What could I be doing wrong in the above and why does it always return null. What do I need to satisfy the method in order for it to return the correct expected value?

Comment: I could be wrong - but doesn't `Url.Action` validate both the Controller and the Action method, and drops any part that it cant verify the existence of?

Comment: @SamAxe I believe so, because it has to look at the routing to generate the correct URL since it isn't necessarily always `/Controller/Action?id=...`.  I'm not sure if userId and token plus routing might play a role as well.  I'd say add the method signature and class definition of the controller/action.  Also make sure to include any attributes on either the class or action as both can have an effect depending on what they are.

Comment: @SamAxe yes you are right, your explanation, combined with Fei Han's answer I was able to do a bit more research and found an example which I was able to modify and make it work for my case. And yes I was missing the "ConfirmEmail" method on the controller which was needed as mentioned

Answer (score 5):

> trying to build a email confrimation link using asp.net core 3. After generating the token, generating a confirmEmail link with this code always returns null.

In [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#changes-to-link-generation), you could find:

```
Generating a URI for an invalid route (a controller/action or page that doesn't 

exist) will produce an empty string under endpoint routing instead of producing 

an invalid URI.
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. I can say I have finally resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

To answer my question based off the feedback and answers given was able to dig around a bit more on what I was missing. The implementation below solved  my issue and I was able to generate an email confirmation link.

Below is the implementation:

```
var confirmationLink = Url.Action(nameof(ConfirmEmail), "Users", new { token, email = user.Email }, Request.Scheme);
```

Passed the "ConfirmEmail" method the nameof() operator as well as setting the user email. Not sure what goes on in the background with that whole implementation but will save that for another day.

Confirm EMail method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string token, string email)
{
     var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
     // More logic....

     var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
     // More logic.... return whether success or failure
}
```